# implicit operator using interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, casting, implicit-conversion

I have a generic class that I'm trying to implement implicit type casting for.  While it mostly works, it won't work for interface casting.  Upon further investigation, I found that there is a compiler error: "User-defined conversion from interface" that applies.  While I understand that this should be enforced in some cases, what I'm trying to do does seem like a legitimate case.

Here's an example:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IBar
{
    private readonly T instance;

    public Foo(T instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public T Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    public static implicit operator Foo<T>(T instance)
    {
        return new Foo<T>(instance);
    }
}
```

Code to use it:

```
var concreteReferenceToBar = new ConcreteBar();
IBar intefaceReferenceToBar = concreteReferenceToBar;
Foo<ConcreteBar> concreteFooFromConcreteBar = concreteReferenceToBar;
Foo<IBar> fooFromConcreteBar = concreteReferenceToBar;
Foo<IBar> fooFromInterfaceBar = intefaceReferenceToBar; // doesn't work
```

Does anyone know a workaround, or can anyone explain in a satisfactory way why I shuouldn't be able to cast `interfaceReferenceToBar` implicitly to `Foo<IBar>`, since in my case it is not being converted, but only contained within Foo?

**EDIT:**
It looks like covariance might offer salvation.  Let's hope the C# 4.0 specification allows for implicit casting of interface types using covariance.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The reason you can't do this is because it is specifically forbidden in the C# language specification:

[Source: ECMA-334 Section 15.10.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf)

> A class or struct is permitted to
> declare a conversion from a source
> type S to a target type T provided all
> of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - Neither S nor T is `object` or an *interface-type*.

and

> User-defined conversions are not
> allowed to convert from or to
> *interface-types*. In particular, this
> restriction ensures that no
> user-defined transformations occur
> when converting to an *interface-type*,
> and that a conversion to an
> *interface-type* succeeds only if the
> object being converted actually
> implements the specified
> *interface-type*.

Comment: I understand that it's part of the specification, implicit casting of an interface should be invalid in some cases, but in all?

Comment: I agree with you, I don't know why they made it invalid for all cases.    In this case you can determine at compile time that the cast is (should be) valid.

Comment: I *believe* that the restriction on implicit interface casting has to do with how COM interop is implemented. COM uses QueryInterface, which .NET handles automatically. Allowing implicit interface conversion would interfere.

Comment: @MichaelMeadows, you may be enlightened to read the responses by Adam Houldsworth and Eric Lippert on [my similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229928/more-on-implicit-conversion-operators-and-interfaces-in-c-sharp-again) in the C# 4.0 context.

Comment: Does it explain why they made this decision anywhere?