# Why can't I return an Interface on implicit casting, but ExpandoObject can?

Tags: c#, dynamic, interface, casting, expandoobject

I have a `DynamicObject`and I want it to be castable to IDictionary, exactly the same way as `ExpandoObject`. For example, casting an ExpandoObject to IDictionary  is perfectly valid:

```
dynamic ex = new ExpandoObject ();
ex.Field = "Foobar";
IDictionary<string, object> dict = ex as IDictionary<string, object>;
Console.WriteLine (dict["Field"]);
```

Now I try to implement this into my own DynamicObject:

```
public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> members = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

    public override bool TryGetMember (GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (members.ContainsKey (binder.Name)) {
            result = members[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        else {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override bool TrySetMember (SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        this.members.Add (binder.Name, value);
        return true;
    }
    public static implicit operator IDictionary<string, object> (MyDynamicObject mydo) 
    {
        return (IDictionary<string, object>) mydo.members;
    }
}
```

But the compiler will fail on the `public static implicit operator IDictionary<string, object>`line, giving the error: "Cannot convert to or from an interface type". If I change the implicit operator to Dictionary, I can cast MyDynamicObject to Dictionary without any Problems, but not IDictionary.

How does ExpandoObject does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) simply implements `IDictionary<string, object>`.

If you want to have the same behaviour, you also need to implement this interface and delegate all calls to your `members` field.

Something like this:

```
public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> members = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return members.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        members.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: For the OP - all you need to do is: do this too, i.e. `public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>` and fill in the missing methods

Comment: Thanks for the very quick responses! Your answer makes perfectly sense. However I will go with just adding Dictionary<string,object> and cast to Dictionary, which is enough for my project.

Comment: Using ReSharper, this task is done in 2 minutes, via the "Delegating members" option.

Answer (score 0):

Cast operators are not interrogated by the DLR - therefore this will not work.

You can inherit from `IDictionary` or you can override the [`TryConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert.aspx) method.

Since implementing `IDictionary` requires either implementing or stubbing out lots of operations, as well, you might find that the `TryConvert` route is actually easier to implement; the downside is that in your implementation of `TryConvert` you will almost certainly produce a new instance of a dictionary each time you call it (unless you cache the result *and* keep it up to date) so it might take an extra performance hit

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in the C# specification:

> A class or struct is permitted to
>   declare a conversion from a source
>   type S to a target type T provided all
>   of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - Neither S nor T is `object` or an *interface-type*.

See [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143485/implicit-operator-using-interfaces) answer.