# Implicit casting IEnumerable to generic type

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I've encountered an interesting case when playing with implicit casts and IEnumerable - please look at the last line of attached code - it won't compile.

```cs
public class Outer<T>
{
    private T field;
    public Outer(T it)
    {
        field = it;
    }

    public static implicit operator Outer<T> (T source)
    {
        return new Outer<T>(source);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Outer<string> intsample = "aa";
    Outer<IList<object>> listsample = new List<object>();

    //The line below fails with:
    //CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'
    //to 'UserQuery.Outer<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>>'.
    //An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    Outer<IEnumerable<object>> enumerablesample = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
}
```

I have a very strong gut feeling, that it is elated to `IEnumerable` being covariant, but could someone explain that more formal?

Comment: Why not cast explicitely?

Comment: Because that is only example to show the problem, implicit casting is very convenient if you use libraries like LangugeExt and its Either type. Unfortunately, I cannot understand marking it as a duplicate and point to not so-related answers about variance and inheritence.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have to agree that this question isn't directly answered by the duplicates. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Agreed........ @Mafii

Comment: Probably has to do with T being an interface: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143567/292411

Comment: @NikodemRafalski it doesn't like `Outer<ICollection<int>> x = (ICollection<int>)new List<int>();` either

Comment: @NikodemRafalski no it does not

Comment: Why not just set it to null.

Comment: @jdweng null and a Empty enumerable are very different.

Comment: Funny enough calling `Enumerable.Empty<object>().ToList()` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664464(v=vs.71).aspx) state:

> A class or struct is permitted to declare a conversion from a source
>   type S to a target type T provided all of the following are true:
>
> - S and T are different types.
> - Either S or T is the class or struct type in which the operator declaration takes place.
> - **Neither S nor T is object or an interface-type**. T is not a base class of S, and S is not a base class of T.

The simple fix is to change:

```
Enumerable.Empty<object>();
```

to:

```
new List<object>();
```

*Which works since `List` is not an interface (thanks @PatrickHofman!).*

Comment: You are simply repeating the duplicate which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143567/993547

Comment: And it is not odd it works: `List<T>` isn't an interface, it is a concrete type.

Comment: Good call - thanks @PartrickHofman !